# Partial template specialization based on argument traits

Tags: c++, template-specialization, sfinae

Suppose I have the following template:

```
template <typename T> union example {
    T t;

    constexpr example(const T & t) : t(t) {};

    /* We rely on owning class to take care
     * of destructing the active member */
    ~example() {};
};
```

Because of the destructor there, `example<T>` will never be trivially destructible (and thus not, say, a literal type). I'd *like* to have a partial specialization like

```
template <typename T> union
    example<std::enable_if_t<std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value, T>> {
    T t;

    constexpr example(const T & t) : t(t) {};
};
```

to let `example<T>` be trivially destructible when `T` is, but unfortunately that gives me the (reasonable, in hindsight) warning

> warning: class template partial specialization contains a template
>   parameter that can not be deduced;
>         this partial specialization will never be used

So is there any way to get what I want here?

Comment: Why do you need to explicitly write the dtor? Can't you `=default` it? (Or is this not possible if its implicit definition would be deleted?)

Comment: Alas, `=default` sets the destructor deleted if `T` is not trivially destructible, at least on clang 3.4.

Comment: @dyp: That doesn't make sense for a union. See 9.5/2: The destructor must be user-provided.

Comment: @KerrekSB True, I wasn't sure if explicitly defaulting might override (implicit) `=delete`. It does not. [dcl.fct.def.default]/4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe with a second, defaulted template parameter?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, bool = std::is_trivially_destructible<T>::value>
union example {
    T t;

    constexpr example(const T & t) : t(t) {};

    /* We rely on owning class to take care
     * of destructing the active member */
    ~example() { std::cout << "primary template\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
union example<T, true> {
    T t;

    constexpr example(const T & t) : t(t) {};
};


struct nontrivial
{
    ~nontrivial() { std::cout << "woot!\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    example<nontrivial> e1{{}};
    example<int> e2{{}};
}
```